# Confusion over singular or plural case

Tags: grammaticality, grammatical-number

Which one is correct?

- Our software solution contains **a set of** libraries and manuals that ***allows*** efficient handling of user requests.
- Our software solution contains a set of **libraries and manuals** that ***allow*** efficient handling of user requests.

Does the "a set of" makes it singular? It seems more natural to use plural form though, so I dunno!

Comment: I'd say that "that" refers to "libraries and manuals", and hence the verb should be the plural "allow".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have posed the question, "that" refers to "a set".

While it refers to multiple things, a set is one thing from a linguistic standpoint (which you can tell because it is using the article "a" --> "...a set of..."

So using **allows** is absolutely correct here.